# execution of if_php_statement and javascript between mysqli_ query and or die() statement?

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

Can I have an if_php_statement before the `or die()` statement?

My code is something like this:

```
<?php
    $var=mysqli_query($db, $sql)

    if($var){

    echo"<img id='success' src='success.jpg'>
    <script>
    $('#success').fadeIn();
    $('#success').fadeOut(1000);
    </script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo"<img id='failure' src='failure.jpg'>
    <script>
    $('#failure').fadeIn();
    $('#failure').fadeOut(1000);
    </script>";
    }

    or die("Error");
?>
```

I am trying to appear an image for a while in case of success or failure before the or die statement is executed. I tried but without success. Is there anything alternative and similar to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace the double quotes with single quotes or escape it `\"`, and you missed the semicolon after `mysqli_query()`

I don't know what you exactly want but if you want to echo something before your die() comes, you can do it like this:

```
$var= mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if( $var ){
echo"<img id='success' src='success.jpg'>
<script>
$('#success').fadeIn();
$('#success').fadeOut(1000);
</script>";
} else {
echo"<img id='failure' src='failure.jpg'>
<script>
$('#failure').fadeIn();
$('#failure').fadeOut(1000);
</script>";
die( "Error" );
}
?>
```

If this is you complete PHP snippet I think you don't need the `die()`, it might be OK just to print out the failure image

Comment: ok, no problem, the semicolon of course is just needed in my solution if you have `$var=mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("Error");`the semicolon isn't needed after ...query() of course

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to check if the query is successful and if so display the success image, if not display a failure image. If that is correct try..

```
if($var=mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
     echo "<img id='success' src='success.jpg'>
     <script>
     $('#success').fadeIn();
     $('#success').fadeOut(1000);
     </script>";
} else {
     echo "<img id='failure' src='failure.jpg'>
     <script>
     $('#failure').fadeIn();
     $('#failure').fadeOut(1000);
     </script>";
     die('query failed?');
}
```

Comment: but I need to have an "or die" statement because I don't want to continue the execution

Comment: When do you want the `die` if the failure image is displayed? before (if before image wont display)?

Comment: after the display of the image

Comment: Thanks, comment wasn't to you but to downvoter. Anonymous uncommented downvotes are pointless, tells no one issue seen or if there actually is one.

Answer (score -1):

You need use the quotes properly by either escaping the `"` or using a single `'`:

```
<?php
   $var=mysqli_query($db, $sql);

  if($var){
    echo"<img id='success' src='success.jpg'>
    <script>
    $('#success').fadeIn();
    $('#success').fadeOut(1000);
    </script>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo"<img id='failure' src='failure.jpg'>
    <script>
    $('#failure').fadeIn();
    $('#failure').fadeOut(1000);
    </script>";
    }
?>
```